# Open Default mail account in Outlook 2010 in C#

Tags: c#

recently i just upgrade my outlook 2007 to 2010. And now my application is not opening default mail account. It is just opening another mail account which is not default. My Application is in C#

```
Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem) outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));
```

Comment: We're probably going to need some more details, e.g. how you're integrating with outlook, how exactly you're opening the account and maybe more details of the correct account and the wrong account. Have you got some code you can show us?

Comment: Outlook.Application outlookApp = new Outlook.Application();
                Outlook.MailItem email = (Outlook.MailItem)(outlookApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem));